# How to change the context of a port 2658 by using Selinux?

Tags: rhel, selinux

I am using RHEL8 and want to change the context port. Does anyone know how to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use semanage assuming your custom type for port 2658 exists, and you're deploying to a vanilla RHEL server.

`semanage port -a -t <custom_type_here> -p <protocol> <port_here>`

Assuming protocol is tcp based:
`semanage port -a -t my_2658_t -p tcp 2658`

More complicated deployments should probably customize [corenetwork.te](https://github.com/SELinuxProject/refpolicy/blob/43d0b184b594394136783771760658613e8e0f0c/policy/modules/kernel/corenetwork.te.in) directly.